# Proper AT-command sequence for an UDP datagram sending

Tags: udp, iot, at-command, gprs, sim800

Could you please help to eliminate my confusion?

I am reading AT commands manual for my SIM800L module, everything is clear in scope of a single command. But it is not clear which sequence is best when sending a UDP packet.

So, I know the order of commands is following:

```
AT+CIICR        Brings up wireless connection
AT+CIFSR        Get local IP address
AT+CIPSTART     Establishes a connection with a server.
AT+CIPSEND      Sends data when the a connection is established.
AT+CIPCLOSE
```

OK but I need to send datagrams time-to-time. Say, the period is from minutes to hour.

I see that AT+CIICR can return ALREADY CONNECTED for subsequent calls, and I guess I should not call it more than once.
So the question is: which sequence should be used for the next datagrams?:

1)

```
AT+CIPSTART
AT+CIPSEND
AT+CIPCLOSE
```

or just:

2)

```
AT+CIPSEND
```

and AT+CIPCLOSE somewhere before a modem shutdown.

Is there any time-to-live of AT+CIPSTART state?
What is the best practice?